# Please check my Huffman tree

Tags: algorithms, greedy-algorithms, data-compression, huffman-coding

My professor gave an example of Huffman tree.

Given inputs

```
a 80
b 10
c 20
d 50
e 100
f 35
g 60
```

… then the tree will be:

[image: Professor's given Huffman tree]

But when i tried to solve it at home, I get this answer:

[image: My Huffman tree]

Which is correct, and why?

Comment: The answer is not unique, depending on how you break ties and combine subtrees. However, in yours, it looks like you combined a tree with weight 65 and 50 as opposed to the ones with weight 60 and 50.

Comment: @user340082710 i'm very grateful for your comment,but is it both correct or not ?

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.

Answer (score 2):

The average codeword length of your professor's code is $2.577$.

The average codeword length of your code is $2.662$.

Huffman's algorithm produces a code minimizing the average codeword length.

You draw the conclusions.